# Change Salesrule DiscountAmount in Install Script

Tags: magento-enterprise

I want to change the amount of a specific sales rule via an instsall script.

This is my install code:

```
$inviterValue = "5";
$inviterId = Mage::getStoreConfig('xxx/bm_invitation_coupon_ids/inviter_coupon_id');
$inviteeValue = "15";
$inviteeId = Mage::getStoreConfig('xxx/bm_invitation_coupon_ids/invitee_coupon_id');

/** @var Bm_SalesRule_Model_Rule $couponsChange */
$couponsChange = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
$couponsChange->load($inviterId)->setDiscountAmount($inviterValue)->save();
```

If I use this code in a phtml file, the change is applied. If I have this in my install-0.0.1.php, it does not.

Why and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my findings there are Mage::-Godclass operations that don't work on the sql install level.

If you need to receive XML data settings, you should use the `data`-way to do operations based on a higher level of execution in Magento.

Data structure:

```
- Vendor
  - Modulename
    - data
      - vendor_modulename_setup
        - data-install-0.0.1.php
    - sql
      - vendor_modulename_setup
        - install-0.0.1.php
```

Also, the data install does not work without resource node in the config.xml and a install-script.

In `data-install-0.0.1.php` you can access highlevel Mage Functions such as `Mage::getStoreConfig`.